# How to Remove IndentationError: expected an indented block: except ValueError: in Google Colab

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

Given a dataset I was asked to perform 5 machine learning models on the dataset.

Here is my code:

```py
standard_scaler = StandardScaler()
try:
  X_train=standard_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
  X_test=standard_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

except ValueError:
```

I keep getting

```
except ValueError:
                 ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Can someone please help me figure out this issue?

Comment: At the very least you need a `pass` within `except ValueError:`. An `except` statement requires an indented block following it.

Comment: Hello, this only worked for 2/5 of the machine learning models I have but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a block in ValueError:

```
standard_scaler = StandardScaler()
try:
  X_train=standard_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
  X_test=standard_scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
except ValueError:
    pass  #or any other value you need
```